# codeigniter email attachment

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a working form which sends email... Now i would like to add attachment.

i have this in view file..

```
 <form  action="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/order/email_invoice/<?php echo   $invoice_info->invoice_no ?>" id="formid" method="POST"  >

    <center> <input type = "text" name="email" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer Email Address"  /></center>


    </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info " >Email to Customer</button></div>

    </div>

</form>
```

and i have this in my controller..

```
 //sender email
        $to = $_POST['email'];

        //subject
        $subject = 'Invoice no:' . $id;
        $attachment = $_FILES['attachment'];
        // set view page
        $view_page = $this->load->view('admin/order/pdf_order_invoice', $data, true);
        $send_email = $this->mail->sendEmail($from, $to, $subject, $view_page);
        if ($send_email) {
            $this->message->custom_success_msg('admin/order/order_invoice/' . $id,
                'Your email has been send successfully!');
        } else {
            $this->message->custom_error_msg('admin/order/order_invoice/' . $id,
                'Sorry unable to send your email!');
```

i want to attach this link to the form so its sent the pdf file to controller and email this file as a attachment. How do i do that?Pls help..

```
<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/order/pdf_invoice/<?php echo $invoice_info->invoice_no ?>
```

Comment: go through this link http://developer-paradize.blogspot.in/2014/03/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
      $this->email->from('abc@gmail.com');
      $this->email->to($email);
      $this->email->subject($subject);
      $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->attach('C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\images\abc.png');
      if($this->email->send())
     {
      echo 'Email send.';
     }
     else
    {
     show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
```

Comment: The things is my attachment contain in this link in PDF format. `<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/order/pdf_invoice/<?php echo $invoice_info->invoice_no ?>`  Its not an external attachment. The attachment from the DB.